# Not able to unlock locked windows file folder

Tags: powershell, file, directory, file-permissions, locked-files

I have one utility provided by Dev, Which takes the firmware package as input and decrypts its content. After decrypts, it asks for a physical device to flash this decrypted content into that device. But before flashing, it creates one locked folder on my machine.

I am trying to unlock that locked window file folder.

[image]

Nothing happened when I tried to open it by double-clicking on the folder icon. Also, Write error occurred When I wanted to rename it using PowerShell.

```
PS C:\Users\RajNegi\AppData\Roaming> rename-item

cmdlet Rename-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\vsc.{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
NewName: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\vsc
rename-item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\vsc.{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ rename-item
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\abc...f-00c04f60b9f0}:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Note: I already set Full control in folder permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a similar program like https://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/Unique_Folder_Protection/coolcode_demo3.zip was used to lock the folder. You can use the same utility to unlock the folder. However, keep in mind that It may ask for the password so you can use the command line to navigate in the locked folder and you will find a pom.xml file that contains the password between XML tags.

Also, It seems like you don't have ownership of this folder currently that's why you are not able to rename it. I have used several tools but this tool [Take Ownership Pro](https://www.top-password.com/take-ownership-pro.html) always worked for me.

Use the Take ownership tool first and then use the 1st link to remove folder protection.